# searching a txt file with jquery to find element and display next line

Tags: jquery, search, import

i am trying to jquery a file preferably .txt but can be .html of which there is example

Group 1:

Score:

Group 2:

score:

Can i use jquery within html to search for 'Group 2' and display the next line in div?

Comment: You can't look directly through your files on the hard drive since javascript doesn't have access to your file system. That being said, no, you can't use jQuery for this.

Comment: If it's just text, no you can't search like you would with DOM elements, but you can split on newlines and use string methods like indexOf to find the right lines etc.

Comment: if you put that in a HTML structure, then you can fetch it with ajax and search in in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't normally use jQuery to go directly to the file.

It'd be better to use some server side code to parse the parse the file, return it in some meaningful state (JSON maybe)?  Then return that into a div with jQuery rather than parsing the text with it.

This way you can still manipulate the HTML with jQuery but the actual processing of the file would be done server side, which would be better anyway as it would mean say if you had a really large file to parse, you can't just hang the browser.

Although technically you may be able to get around it so you could do a ajax request to get the file, it would probably be a pain in the ass to support.

Comment: Thank you all, of course all right and i ended up learning MySql instead :) and thank god i did. Eyes, opened!